# Why is $ U \otimes \operatorname{Ind}(W) = \operatorname{Ind}(\operatorname{Res}(U) \otimes W)$?

Tags: representation-theory

If $U$ is a representation of $G$ and $W$ is a representation of $H$, then why is $$ U \otimes \operatorname{Ind}(W) = \operatorname{Ind}(\operatorname{Res}(U) \otimes W)$$

I've tried to simply use the definitions to prove they are equal, but I've hit a road block.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I take it $H \leq G$.  These reps are not equal, but they are isomorphic.  It will be more natural to prove that $ (W \otimes U|_H) \uparrow^G \cong (W \uparrow ^G)  \otimes U $, but this is equivalent as $A\otimes B \cong B \otimes A$ for modules over group algebras.

We want a module map $kG \otimes_H (W \otimes U|_H) \to (kG\otimes_H W) \otimes U$. Take $\beta: x\otimes (w \otimes u) \mapsto (x\otimes w) \otimes x u $.  This is easily verified to be a module map (and well-defined: there is an issue because of the $\otimes_H$).

Now define $\alpha :  (kG\otimes_H W) \otimes U \to kG \otimes_H (W \otimes U|_H)$ by $(x \otimes w) \otimes u \mapsto x \otimes ( w \otimes x^{-1} u )$.  This is inverse to $\beta$, and is well-defined and a module map: thus the two modules are isomorphic.

Surprisingly, all this generalises to arbitrary Hopf algebras (even non-cocommutative ones).  The maps are slightly more messy to write down though.

Comment: Is there a proof of this using Frobenius reciprocity? I think there is, and it'd be nice to know (nicer than having to explicitly define an isomorphism, at least)

Comment: The way the module map is defined, it could confuse the reader. One will need to check that the map $(x,w,u)\mapsto ((x\otimes w)\otimes xu)$ is multilinear, which it is not in the first variable. I guess you wanted to define the map on certain summands, as is done in my answer below.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a proof ${\rm Ind}_H^G(V\otimes{\rm Res}_H^GW)\cong({\rm Ind}_H^GV)\otimes W$ are isomorphic using the categorial version of Frobenius reciprocity (that $\rm Ind$, $\rm Res$ are adjoint functors), as well as three other lemmas:

**Lemma I**. If $\hom_G(A,U)\cong\hom_G(B,U)$ for all $U\in{\rm Rep}(G)$ then $A\cong B$.

**Lemma II** (Frobenius reciprocity). $\hom_G({\rm Ind}_H^GA,B)\cong\hom_H(A,{\rm Res}_H^GB)$.

**Lemma III** (currying). $\hom_H(A\otimes B,C)\cong\hom_H(A,B^*\otimes C)$.

**Lemma IV**. $({\rm Res}_H^GA)^*\cong{\rm Res}_H^G(A^*)$ and $({\rm Res}_H^GA)\otimes({\rm Res}_H^GB)\cong{\rm Res}_H^G(A\otimes B)$.

We employ the last three lemmas to verify the hypothesis of the first lemma: for all $U\in{\rm Rep}(G)$,

$$\begin{array}{llll} & \hom_G({\rm Ind}_H^G(V\otimes{\rm Res}_H^GW),U) & \cong & \hom_H(V\otimes{\rm Res}_H^GW,{\rm Res}_H^GU) \\ \cong & \hom_H(V,({\rm Res}_H^GW)^*\otimes{\rm Res}_H^GU) & \cong & \hom_H(V,{\rm Res}_H^G(W^*\otimes U)) \\ \cong & \hom_G({\rm Ind}_H^GV,W^*\otimes U) & \cong & \hom_G(({\rm Ind}_H^GV)\otimes W,U). \end{array}$$

Hence ${\rm Ind}_H^G(V\otimes{\rm Res}_H^GW)\cong({\rm Ind}_H^GV)\otimes W.$

In fact the functors ${\rm Ind}_H^G(-\otimes{\rm Res}_H^G-)$ and $({\rm Ind}_H^G-)\otimes-:{\rm Rep}(H)\times{\rm Rep}(G)\to{\rm Rep}(G)$ should be naturally isomorphic (via a canonical isomorphism mt_ gave). All of the isomorphisms in the above calculation are natural, but I am not sure how to successfully upgrade Lemma I to talk about naturality.

Answer (score 6):

For someone looking for a more down to earth answer, firstly note that

$U \otimes$ Ind $W = U \otimes \left(\bigoplus_{\sigma \in G/H}\sigma \cdot W \right)\cong \bigoplus_{\sigma \in G/H} \left(U \otimes \sigma \cdot W \right)$.

Then, define a map $\Phi$ by
\begin{align}
\Phi : Ind (Res(U)\otimes W) \longrightarrow  \bigoplus_{\sigma \in G/H} \left(U \otimes \sigma \cdot W \right) \\
g_{\sigma}\cdot(u\otimes w) \mapsto g_{\sigma}u\otimes g_{\sigma}\cdot w 
\end{align}
and extend linearly.

You should be  able to show that this defines an isomorphism of vector spaces. Furthermore, recalling that,

$g \cdot (g_{\sigma}\cdot w) = g_{\tau} \cdot (hw)$
where $gg_{\sigma} = g_{\tau}h$ for some $\tau \in G/H, h \in H$,

you should then be able to prove that $\Phi$ is $G$-equivariant.

Comment: Finally... this is by far the most understandable proof (at least for me) out of every proof here. I was having a hard time understanding it and the other answers are using lemmas that I have yet to seen, or are being too pedantic in a way that makes it hard to understand. Thank you very much, I honestly wish I could've put a reward on this answer.

Answer (score 1):

When characteristic k=0, we can see this, using Frobenius Reciprocity, as follows. Recall that Frobenius reciprocity says the following:
$${\rm Hom}_G({\rm Ind}(W),U)\cong{\rm Hom}_H(W,U).$$
Thus, we have, for a $G$ representation $M$
\begin{align}
{\rm Hom}_G({\rm Ind}(W\otimes U),M)&\cong {\rm Hom}_H(W\otimes U,M) \\\\
                             &\cong {\rm Hom}_H(W,U^{-1}\otimes M) \\\\
                             &\cong {\rm Hom}_G({\rm Ind}(W),U^{-1}\otimes M) \\\\
                             &\cong {\rm Hom}_G({\rm Ind}(W)\otimes U,M)
\end{align}
Now letting $M$ vary over the irreducible representations of $G$, we see that the irreducible representations appear with the same multiplicity. This proves that both are isomorphic. This part is more or less same as the answer by anon above.

However, we can be more explicit and describe the isomorphism. This part is more or less same as the answers given by Matthew Towers and Sunny Sood above. Recall that we may write the representation
$${\rm Ind}(W\otimes U)=\bigoplus_i g_i\otimes (W\otimes E),$$
where $g_i$ run over right coset representatives for $H$, that is, $G=\bigsqcup g_iH$. Similarly, we may write
$${\rm Ind}(W)\otimes U=\Big(\bigoplus_i g_i\otimes W\Big)\otimes E.$$
Define a map ${\rm Ind}(W\otimes U)\to {\rm Ind}(W)\otimes U$ by defining it on the summand $g_i\otimes (W\otimes E)$ as follows. On pure tensors define it as :
$$g_i\otimes (w\otimes e)\mapsto (g_i\otimes w)\otimes g_ie.$$
It is easy to check that this becomes a morphism of $G$-representations. Similarly, define the inverse map by defining it on pure tensors as
$$(g_i\otimes w)\otimes e\mapsto g_i\otimes (w\otimes g_i^{-1}e).$$