# Is $\sigma \operatorname{Res}_H^G(U) \cong U$ if $\sigma \in G/H$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is $ U \otimes \operatorname{Ind}(W) = \operatorname{Ind}(\operatorname{Res}(U) \otimes W)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66323/why-is-u-otimes-operatornameindw-operatornameind-operatornameres)

I am working on a problem out of Fulton and Harris:

Show that $U \otimes \operatorname{Ind} W \cong \operatorname{Ind}(\operatorname{Res}(U)\otimes W)$

Expanding this out from the left I get to a point where $\bigoplus_{\sigma \in G/H} U \otimes \sigma W$ and by expanding from the right I get to a point where $\bigoplus_{\sigma \in G/H} \sigma \operatorname{Res}_H^G U \otimes \sigma W$.

The only remaining step, if I have done everything correctly thus far, is to show that $\sigma \operatorname{Res}_H^G(U) \cong U$ if $\sigma \in G/H$.

From what I understand, as a vector space $\operatorname{Res} U= U$. The only difference is that as a representation they are different. Thus perhaps it is better to specify where my tensors are being taken: $U \otimes_G \operatorname{Ind} W \cong \operatorname{Ind}(\operatorname{Res}(U)\otimes_{H} W)$ and thus the expansions from the left and right are $\bigoplus_{\sigma \in G/H} U \otimes_G \sigma W$ and $\bigoplus_{\sigma \in G/H} \sigma \operatorname{Res}_H^G U \otimes_H \sigma W$. But such makes me believe I made a mistake since $\sigma \operatorname{Res}_H^G U \otimes_H \sigma W$ shouldn't be defined since $\sigma$ may not be in $H$. Thus it should really be $\bigoplus_{\sigma \in G/H} \sigma (\operatorname{Res}_H^G U \otimes_H W)$.

As you can see I am sort of getting stuck in loops here. Please help!

Comment: I was trying to think of this stuff in terms of group rings. So $U$ is an $FG$ module and $Res(U)$ is an $FH$ module. Is it the case in general for an $FG$ module $M$ that $\sigma Res_H^G M$ where $\sigma \in G/H$ is isomorphic (perhaps naturally/canonically?) to $M$

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66323/why-is-u-otimes-operatornameindw-operatornameind-operatornameres/66328#66328